# Python Request library not helping in Getting the correct webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, get, scrapy, request

I have this website:

```
https://xueqiu.com/hq#exchange=CN&firstName=1&secondName=1_0
```

I am trying to get this webpage through Python's get request. I have also tried changing "user-agent".
But I am not able to get the webpage, I am new to this parsing.

```
    url = 'https://xueqiu.com/hq#exchange=CN&firstName=1&secondName=1_0'
    with request.session() as session:
           response = session.get(url)
```

Could someone please help me how to extract it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data loaded via below url json format. So i  use `json` module to extract the data.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import json
headers={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
}
def scrape(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        r = req.get(url)
        mydata =r.json()
        for data in mydata['data']['list']:
            print(data, sep='*')

url =  'https://xueqiu.com/service/v5/stock/screener/quote/list?page=1&size=30&order=desc&orderby=percent&order_by=percent&market=CN&type=sh_sz&_=1606221698728'
scrape(url)
```

hope its help you.

Comment: Yes, it's working absolutely fine. Can you tell me how you figure out it's uploading data with that url? It will help me in future. Thanks you.

Comment: Open the https://xueqiu.com/hq#exchange=CN&firstName=1&secondName=1_0 on chrome then press ctrl+shift+i then go to network tab click XHR tab.  after that refresh page then under the name tab, You will see the uploading data url. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you think this is a dynamic url? Is there a way to capture the url? 
Sorry for so many questions. But this thing is completely new to me. Thanks.

Comment: Hope this url help you. https://scrapingauthority.com/scrapy-ajax, In this url please see image the go through.

Comment: Thanks alot. This really helped.